# Prettifying/Formatting output in SimpleXML

Tags: php, formatting, simplexml

I have this simplexml script i'm using to post data entered from a form.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("links.xml");

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML()); 

$person = $sxe->addChild("link");
$person->addChild("title", "Q: ".$x_title);
$person->addChild("url", "questions_layout.php#Question$id");

$sxe->asXML("links.xml");
```

and when it comes out it looks like this on one line:

```
<link><title>Alabama State</title><url>questions_layout.php#Question37</url></link><link><title>Michigan State</title><url>questions_layout.php#Question37</url></link></pages>
```

But i've tried the method found [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840148/php-simplexml-new-line) and [**THIS AS WELL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way) but neither format the XML correctly in the lines as they should be like

```
<link>
<title></title>
<url></url>
</link>
```

In the first reference link I even changed `loadXML` to `load`, because `loadXML` expects a string as XML. Can somebody help me find a solution to this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP simpleXML how to save the file in a formatted way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK simpleXML can't do it on its own.

However, DOMDocument can.

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($sxe)->ownerDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$formatted = $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: I tried your answer and i received a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveXML()` on the line where the `$formatted = $dom->saveXML(); happens

Comment: @Tower Try calling `saveXML()` on `ownerDocument`.

Comment: Changed it to `$dom = dom_import_simplexml($sxe)->ownerDocument;` and though the error isn't being printed anymore, the XML is still not being formatted and appears all on one line.

Comment: @Tower How are you viewing it to confirm this?

Comment: I entered data into the form again, submit it, let the PHP do it's job and then take a look at the XML file in Notepad++, but now that i see it, it only appears this way in Notepad++, but in IE or Firefox, it appears organized. Still should i be concerned about making it format properly in the editor as well?

Comment: @Tower So you're using Notepad++ on Windows right? The newline characters are different between Windows and *nix machines.

Comment: @Tower If you convert `\n` to `\n\r`, it should work on Windows.

Comment: How do you mean convert? with a function?

Comment: @Tower A function is one method to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way actually works

Answer (score 2):

i think above accepted answer from stackoverflow authority did not solved above question.
Ref : [ I tried your answer and i received a Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveXML() on the line where the `$formatted = $dom->saveXML();`

```
$simplexml = simplexml_load_file("links.xml");
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($simplexml->asXML());
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($dom->saveXML());

$person = $xml->addChild("link");
$person->addChild("title", "Q: ".$x_title);
$person->addChild("url", "questions_layout.php#Question$id");
$xml->saveXML("links.xml");
```

---

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me and it's also pretty clean:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo $xml->asXML();
```

where $xml is a SimpleXMLElement - this code will print the XML in the following way

```
<Attribute>
   <ChildAttribute>Value</ChildAttribute>
</Attribute>
```

This is taken from the [official PHP documentation SimpleXMLElement::asXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Hope this will help you!