# xml formatting- simple xml does not do pretty formatting (indent formatting)

Tags: php, xml

i am converting php variables into XML format.

i noticed that when i just use the **DOMDocument** along with;

> $dom->formatOutput = true;

to create the XML, it formats correctly (i.e line indenting etc)

**code using just  DOMDocument**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    $root = $dom->createElement('student');
    $dom->appendChild($root);

    $result = $dom->createElement('result');
    $root->appendChild($result);

    $result->setAttribute('id', 1);
    $result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('name', 'Opal Kole') );
    $result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('sgpa', '8.1') );
    $result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('cgpa', '8.4') );

    echo '<xmp>'. $dom->saveXML() .'</xmp>';
    $dom->save('result.xml') or die('XML Create Error');
```

**The Result **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student>
  <result id="1">
    <name>Opal Kole</name>
    <sgpa>8.1</sgpa>
    <cgpa>8.4</cgpa>
  </result>
</student>
```

However if i try using **simplexml** with the **domDocument**  it no longer formats correctly ;

below is a sample of the problem

```
$dom = new domDocument; 

$dom->formatOutput = true;   
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "user" ));    
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );     
$sxe->addChild("firstname", "John");    
$sxe->addChild("surname", "Brady"); 

$sxe->asXML('testingXML.xml');
```

**the result;**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user><firstname>John</firstname><surname>Brady</surname></user>
```

you will note that it no longer formats in the desired way.

i have followed all the online tutorial examples that combine simple xml with the dom but none of them format correctly.

**UPDATE**

i tried many of the solution on the forumns but non seemed to work for me.

however,i have just found this solution- it does indeed work- however, its long winded. it requires me to first save the file using the simplyXML and to then reload the the saved file and NOW save it using the DocumentDom:

```
 $sxe->asXML('simple_xml_create.xml');

    $simplexml = simplexml_load_file("simple_xml_create.xml");
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($simplexml->asXML());
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($dom->saveXML());


$xml->saveXML("simple_xml_create.xml");
```

IS THERE A MORE ELEGANT SOLUTION ?

Comment: Have your searched for this particular problem? It seems not at all. There are a myriad of results on Google but even here on SO you will find a number of answers all saying the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prettifying/Formatting output in SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133157/prettifying-formatting-output-in-simplexml)

Comment: i did indeed. i tried this;  $sxe->asXML('simple_xml_create.xml');
    
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($sxe->asXML());
echo $dom->saveXML();
    but it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP simpleXML how to save the file in a formatted way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you were successful in finding out that **DOMDocument** supports formatted XML while **SimpleXMLElement** does not. And that is totally correct.

So as you want to use **SimpleXMLElement** to actually create the XML document but you also want to benefit from the formatting options from **DOMDocument** you might want to learn about the fact that both libraries are sister-libraries that work very well with each other. You already sort of seem to know about that as you make use of `simplexml_import_dom` to convert a **DOMNode** object into it's **SimpleXMLElement** object.

You however seem to miss how near you already were. Please see the following example which I copied from your question - I just added a single line at the very end (and change the filename to standard output so it echoes out the documents):

```
$dom = new domDocument;

$dom->formatOutput = true;
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "user" ));
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
$sxe->addChild("firstname", "John");
$sxe->addChild("surname", "Brady");

$sxe->asXML('php://output');
$dom->save('php://output');
```

The `SimpleXMLElement::saveXML()` method will use non-formatted output while the `DOMDocument::save()` method will use the formatting as you set the parameters for:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user><firstname>John</firstname><surname>Brady</surname></user>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
  <surname>Brady</surname>
</user>
```

And that's it already.